# Add documents to existing envelope

Tags: node.js

I am following the (LESSON 3) on https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-docusign-rest-api-add-additional-documents-envelope/ to add additional documents to my existing draft envelope, only I am using the nodejs module http://docusign.github.io/docusign-node-client/

so I first login, and create an envelope (with envelope definition with status status: "created" instead of "sent") and then try to run "updateDocuments" as follows:

```
    // create a new envelope object that we will manage the signature request through
    var envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
    var docDef = new docusign.Document();

    docDef = [
      {
        documentId: 1,
        name: "CONTRACT",
        fileExtension: "jpg",
        documentBase64: base64_encode("./someimage.jpg")
      }
    ];
    envDef.documents = docDef;


    envelopesApi.updateDocuments(accountId, envelopeId,
      {"envelopeDefinition": envDef}
    ,function(error, data, response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response,1,2));
        process.exit();
    });
```

console log giving the following error (FORMAT_CONVERSION_ERROR) :

```
{
  "req": {
    "method": "PUT",
    "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/2984497/envelopes/ef87c144-497a-4ce8-8d81-cd1068f90daf/documents",
    "data": {
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentId": 1,
          "name": "contract",
          "fileExtension": "jpg",
          "documentBase64": "***HUGE base64 string***"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "header": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-length": "291",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "x-ratelimit-reset": "1496912400",
    "x-ratelimit-limit": "1000",
    "x-ratelimit-remaining": "995",
    "x-docusign-tracetoken": "b44c0be9-96f3-4348-8e01-04babd762691",
    "date": "Thu, 08 Jun 2017 08:15:46 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "text": "{\r\n  \"envelopeId\": \"ef87c144-497a-4ce8-8d81-cd1068f90daf\",\r\n  \"envelopeDocuments\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"documentId\": \"1\",\r\n      \"order\": \"8\",\r\n      \"errorDetails\": {\r\n        \"errorCode\": \"FORMAT_CONVERSION_ERROR\",\r\n        \"message\": \"The data could not be converted.\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
}
```

according to one answer I googled my content-encoding header isnt correct.. but I don't believe that as the idea is that the json-documentBase64 would be read out, instead of the multipart chunks

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Niels

Answer (score 0):

Nico and Niels,

1. I always recommend configuring the Debug Logging available in DocuSign https://support.docusign.com/articles/API-Request-Logging
2. I always recommend using Postman or SoapUI (both opensource and free, run on both Windows and Mac to then setup the calls from the logging you see. Helps you learn what works best in the API, then Adjust the API SDK code for your platform | language (nodejs in this case) to correctly prepare what you want to send.
3. In General what you plan to do is correct, however until you provide the actual "What was received by DS" it will be very hard to debug a fragment of Code. :-)
4. I prefer composite template model and multi-part form submission for "complicated and exotic" envelope composition and honestly avoid object model due to the cost of spin up and wind down to add just a document, recipient, etc. I do understand this is a choice, however, I have found it lends itself to speed, performance, testability.
5. I have also noticed that Jpg's and images not converted to PDF via Aspose or other utility can cause DocuSign "Third Party Converters (vendor based)" some hiccups, so again for testing, best to have it as pdf and in the base64 version of it first.

Hope this helps and please let us know what you determine and if you add the snips sent|received by DS, several of us may be able to provide more insight. Always great to have what the final issue was to help other devs at 3:00am in need to make a milesote.